# How to switch object load in Swift Scenekit?

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

I want to load objects using iOS SceneKit.

And how do I unload a loaded object and reload another object?

I succeeded in loading the object by referring to the code [below](https://github.com/pjardin/Blender-Motion-Capture/blob/master/Blender%20Motion%20Capture/Blender%20Motion%20Capture/FacialCaptureView.swift).

```
func sceneSetup() {

    if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Smiley", ofType: "scn") {
        let referenceURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)

        self.contentNode = SCNReferenceNode(url: referenceURL)
        self.contentNode?.load()
        self.head.morpher?.unifiesNormals = true // ensures the normals are not morphed but are recomputed after morphing the vertex instead. Otherwise the node has a low poly look.
        self.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(self.contentNode!)
    }
    self.faceView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true

    // set the scene to the view
    self.faceView.scene = self.scene

    // allows the user to manipulate the camera
    self.faceView.allowsCameraControl = false

    // configure the view
    self.faceView.backgroundColor = .clear
}
```

But I don't know how to load and switch multiple objects.

I added testScene.scn to the project and added the code as below, but only the first specified object was loaded.

```
var charaSelect = "Smiley"

//tapEvent(ViewDidLoad)
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(FaceGeoViewController.tapped(_:)))
    tapGesture.delegate = self
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

//tap
 @objc func tapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
 {
    self.charaSelect = "testScene"
 }

func sceneSetup() {

    if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: self.charaSelect, ofType: "scn") {
        let referenceURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)

        self.contentNode = SCNReferenceNode(url: referenceURL)
        self.contentNode?.load()
        self.head.morpher?.unifiesNormals = true // ensures the normals are not morphed but are recomputed after morphing the vertex instead. Otherwise the node has a low poly look.
        self.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(self.contentNode!)
    }
    self.faceView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true

    // set the scene to the view
    self.faceView.scene = self.scene

    // allows the user to manipulate the camera
    self.faceView.allowsCameraControl = false

    // configure the view
    self.faceView.backgroundColor = .clear
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: Hi there, I wanted to clarify, do you want to put several objects and be able to remove some of them as well? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will explain the concept here, but if you may need to see those things as a complete project you are welcome to refer to the [code](https://github.com/bolattleubayev/ARKit-Drawing/blob/master/ARKit-Drawing/ViewController.swift) that I followed from a book [“App Development with Swift”](https://books.apple.com/kz/book/app-development-with-swift/id1219117996) by Apple Education, 2019, particularly the Guided Project in the end of Chapter 3A.

Below you can see the sample screenshot. In the app you can add elements by touching the empty place on the SceneView or when your touch collides with another object (plane). Also, there is a logic for object removal

[image]

So, basically, one way to be able to remove nodes from the scene is to keep track of them in the `ViewController` with a special array `var placedNodes = [SCNNode]()`. That way you can clear the view from all the nodes (for example by creating Button Action "Clear")

Another nice addition that you may grasp from Apple's developers is utilizing not a tap gesture recognizer, but by overriding [touchesBegan](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621142-touchesbegan)/[touchesMoved](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621107-touchesmoved), this may give you more flexibility in terms of what you can do with touch gestures, particularly, you can get its location in the SceneView by calling `touch.location(in: sceneView)`.

So, `touchesBegan/touchesMoved` allow you to locate the places that were tapped by user. This may be used for adding/removing objects on the SceneView

Hope that this will help!